# Flowlayoutpanel creates blank space between controls even though margin and paddings are set to 0

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

[Image where the blank space is visible. The red is the background color of the flowlayoutpanel where all other panels which are inside it are gray.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnpdP.png)

From the image could be seen how the flowlayoutpanel leaves blank space between the categories in my menu even though the margins of all panels are set to 0 including the flowlayoutpanel also all labels and buttons margins are set to 0

Managed to fix my problem by implementing it without flowlayoutpanel by using timers :)

[Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiqgK.png)

I'll leave the question open if somebody knows how to fix the flowlayoutpanel situation

Comment: Have you actually set the Panels: `[Panel].Padding = new Padding(0),
[Panel].Margin = new Padding(0)` when one is created? The same for the FLP? Can you show the code that builds the FLP and the Panels?

Comment: Yes all paddings and margins are set to 0 but this didn't fix the problem. However I decided to try and implement it without flowlayoutpanel as I saw that is some kind of bug related to the flowlayoutpanel's spacing of controls. I managed to do it with timer which synchronises the position of the panels with each other and so I will call it a day :) thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: The FLP has no such *bug*.

Comment: I think it has I saw this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448229/strange-empty-spaces-in-flowlayoutpanel

and tried to do it with mine program but it either I didn't manage to implement it right for my case (most likely :) ) or else happend wrong, sorry for the bad formatting I'm new to the site.

Comment: It's a feature, more or less the same applies to the TableLayoutPanel (related to the row styles). See the notes and try the code here: [Center multiple rows of controls in a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565075/7444103), setting both the FLP containers' Padding/Margin and the child controls'  to `0`. See what happens. (Spoiler alert: all controls will be positioned without any visible space between them).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225457/7444103) there's (more or less) the same code, but there's also a complete Form layout for testing it.

Comment: I put all the child panels, buttons, labels and the FLP's padding and margins to zero when I uploaded the picture (the first one) and the problem was still present I tried many different things using FLP like manipulating the margins in a lot of different ways but alas nothing helped to get rid off that space between the categories. However I actually prefer the solution I made with the timer as it simplifies the things a lot. Thanks for the spared time

Comment: No problem. If you're happy with it, then it's good.